# Regex match any number of periods

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match strings like `$object.child.child.child`.

I have this: `/\$\w+\.?\w+/g` matches 1 child, how do I make it match any number of children.

Comment: Just wrap it with a group and quantify it, `/\$\w+(?:\.\w+)*/g`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Sorry fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `\.?\w+` part in parenthesis, and add `*` to allow repeating

```js
var regex = /\$\w+(\.\w+)*/g
var str = 'some text $object.child.child.child bla bla'
console.log(str.match(regex))
```

Comment: `\.?` must be `\.`

Comment: not really metter, since if there is no `.` it is continue the previous word, wich is still a match. but you right, it is unnecessary. removed